# Found "Place", expected "="

Tags: bibtex

I have the following citation which was copied exactly from the citethisforme bibles output. I'm getting the error Found "Place", expected "=" in Overleaf but I cannot figure out what the problem is

Any ideas?

```
@book{nasuwt_2019,
 place={Birmingham},
 title={The Big Question 2019: An Opinion Survey of Teachers and Headteachers},
 institution={NASUWT},
 author={NASUWT},
 year={2019}
```

Comment: The bib entry you show seems to be missing a `}` at the very end

Answer (score 1):

The standard, or "classic", BibTeX styles -- `plain`, `unsrt`, `abbrv`, `alpha`, and `ieeetr` -- do *not* recognize the field names `place` and `institution` for entries of type `@book`.

The entry type `@book` features the following **required** fields: `author` or `editor`, `title`, `publisher`, and `year`. In addition, the `@book` entry type also recognizes the following **optional** fields: `volume` or `number`, `series`, `address`, `edition`, `month`, and `year`. *All other fields -- including `place` and `institution` -- are not recognized and therefore **ignored**.*

What's the upshot? Assuming that the `@book` entry type is the correct choice, I believe that you should rewrite the entry as

```
@book{nasuwt_2019,
  address  = {Birmingham},
  title    = {The Big Question 2019: An Opinion Survey of Teachers and Headteachers},
  publisher= {NASUWT},
  author   = {{NASUWT}},
  year     = {2019}
}
```